# Spring @Scheduled method Cannot Save with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-scheduled

SpringBoot 1.4.1.RELEASE is used. A simple task is create that runs every 5 seconds. It fetched data from database using Spring Data JPA, sends the data through an API and on success, updates send status in database using Spring Data JPA.

Following is scheduler code snippet

```
@Component
public class MemberJob {
    @Value("${base.url}")
    private String baseApiUrl;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("memberServiceBean")
    private EntityService memberServiceBean;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000l)
    public void runJob() throws Exception {
         Collection<Member> notSynched = memberRepository.findAll();
         notSynched.stream().forEach(m -> {
                //Send to server: on success
                m.setSyncStatus(true);
                memberServiceBean.update(m);
         });
    }
}
```

The problem is on success the member is not updated.For some reasons Spring Data JPA is not working in `@Scheduled` method. How can i make data jpa update this object inside **self-invocation** `@Scheduled` method?

And yes the update method in service layer is decorated with `@Transactional` like so

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Member update(Member m) {
    return (Member) getRepository().save(m);
}
```

### Update

Based on suggestions on comment section, update method is surrounded by `try/catch` unfortunate no exception was caught! Like so

```
 try{
     m = (Member) memberServiceBean.update(m);
 }catch(Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Also in `application.properties` file, `logging.level.org.springframework.transaction.interceptor=TRACE` was added and following trace seen

```
2017-10-07 11:23:21.968 TRACE 2200 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [re.iprocu.service.impl.MemberServiceBean.update]
2017-10-07 11:23:21.969 TRACE 2200 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.save]
2017-10-07 11:23:22.536 TRACE 2200 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.QueryDslJpaRepository.save]
2017-10-07 11:23:22.536 TRACE 2200 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [re.iprocu.service.impl.MemberServiceBean.update]
```

Still no update to database is realized. If any additional information needed, please don't hesitate to ask.

### Update 2

Respository `save` if changed to `saveAndFlush` following exception is caught

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy209.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
at re.iprocu.service.impl.AbstractFacade.update(AbstractFacade.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy237.update(Unknown Source)
at re.iprocu.job.iprocuredata.MemberJob.lambda$runJob$0(MemberJob.java:104)
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
at re.iprocu.job.iprocuredata.MemberJob.runJob(MemberJob.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1136)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1297)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.flush(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy171.flush(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.flush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:553)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.saveAndFlush(SimpleJpaRepository.java:521)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 38 more
```

Comment: What's the exception that u are getting ?

Comment: No any exception is thrown, it just doesn't update

Comment: You are not modifying the object  "Member m" after reading it. It seems you are saving the same object that you have just read.

Comment: Actually i'm changing status, i just didn't show it initially in my question. Now it's there

Comment: Exceptions thrown in a forEach lamba are eaten.  Put a try/catch around the ``memberServiceBean.update()`` call to see if it is throwing.

Comment: @brettw updated post with your suggestions and others

Comment: do you have enabled jpa logs? Add this property to application.properties file `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and look whats happen.

Comment: @Patrick when `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` added, only `select` statements are seen, no `update` or `insert` statement seen

Comment: so it seems that you really dont make an update. Are you really sure that you change properties of your entity. try to change another property instead of your boolean one

Comment: @Patrick, also change another integer property but nothing changed in db. Though when changed `save` to `saveAndFlush` an exception is thrown, check post update 2

Comment: It seems, the transaction is not available when executed the persistence operation. Do you tried the solution in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443876/spring3-s-transactional-scheduled-not-committed-to-db)? use a `TransactionTemplate` to execute a manual transaction.

Comment: @Hantsy i have done that, no change, same exception is thrown

Comment: Another possible solution, switch transaction AOP to AspectJ from JDK proxy. I have encountered the similar problem in before projects, but now I can not remember the exact case. Most of time, I would like to use AspectJ to weave transaction/cache etc, and it also support compile time weaving.

Comment: @Hantsy If i change AOP to AspectJ  will it have a ripple effect to service layer transactions?

Comment: did you try, Propagation REQUIRES_NEW ?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue... nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

Have you resolved this issue without the jdbctemplate?

Weird as @Transactional should just work

Comment: @Multiplexor: No i just went on with jdbcTemplate, though i would appreciate to know the solution

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.  Resolved it with including something like this in my `@Repository` interface:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update coop_member set sync_status = :syncStatus where member_id = :memberId")
void updateSyncStatus(Long memberId, boolean syncStatus);
```

Variable names and types could be different, but the important part was using the `@Modifying` and the `@Query` annotations.

It also assumes marking with `@Transactional` and `@EnableScheduling`.  None of the entity manager flushing/merging or setting propagation/isolation on the transaction worked.  Call that method instead of `save().`

Answer (score 0):

As there is no answer that fixed my saving issue in `@Scheduler` self-invocation method, i decided to use `JdbcTemplate` which does work.

```
 jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE coop_member SET sync_status = ? WHERE member_id = ?", uMember.getSyncStatus(), uMember.getMemberId());
```

In my case i only want to update `sync_status` so it not alot of work.